# django-easy-pdf making the table header show up on each page

Tags: django, pdf

Is there a way in django-easy-pdf to include the table header on each page of the print?

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th> First Name </th><th> Last Name</th> <!--I want this on each page of pdf -->
   </tr>
    {% for employee in employees %}
    <tr>
      <td>  {{ employee.first_name}} </td><td> {{ employee.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently, and the fix happens to be very simple. Group your headers in a `thead` element, and then in the template, add the following CSS.

```css
@media print {
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```